# Java Recursion. Output for the following program

Tags: java, oop, recursion

I am looking for some brief explanations on how the below program or code works.Thanks

```
public void Convert( int iNum )
{
    int m = 0;
    if (iNum == 1 )
        System.out.print( iNum );
    else
    {
        m = iNum % 2;
        Convert(iNum/2);
        System.out.print(m);
    }
}
```

Comment: nope its not. it is something that was there in the exam today. so wondering

Comment: you know something about it ?

Comment: Its a buggy version of the standard recursive routine to print a number in base 2.

Comment: Try compiling and see what it gives you for different inputs.

Comment: i see. so how does this basically work, assuming iNum is some N number ? then going along with it ? or does the program mean something else

Comment: i tried compiling, but the result wasnt supportive to recursion

Comment: @ChrisDodd: Not that buggy. I mean, it'll overflow the stack if `iNum` is negative or zero, but otherwise it should be fine.

Comment: What part of it are you having trouble with, specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This program tries to convert a decimal number to binary using recursion. Lets take an example:

Decimal 5 -> Binary 101

```
Convert(5):
m = 5 %2 -> 1
   Convert(2):
       m -> 2%2 -> 0
       Convert(1)
          The first if is true: -> 1

Output: 101
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a simple recursive call
The if part will get executed only once ie, when inum=1;
The else part keeps only calling convert (each time cutting the value of inum by 2) and when we cannot further dive inum first the if part gets executed and the step back to the next stacked recursive version and prints the remainder we get on dividing inum/2.

Comment: thanks ajay. so in order to have the output the we NEED to pass in a value for iNum. is that right ?